# PHP header() not working during ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, nginx, opencart, php-7

I am migrating opencart 1.5 from apache to nginx and everything is going well except when I make a redirect within an ajax call.

```
//fails, hangs and times out when ajax call
//fine when not in an ajax call
if(true)    
    $this->redirect('path to file',100);
```

The redirect function in opencart 1.5

```
protected function redirect($url, $status = 302, $otherHeaders = []) {
    foreach($otherHeaders as $name => $value)
       header("$name $value");

    header('Status: ' . $status);
    header('Location: ' . str_replace('&amp;', '&', $url));
    exit();
}
```

Comment: hmm, what is the `path to file` that you are passing in when you do ajax and non-ajax call? are you sure you are not going to the same page that has the redirect and therefore entering an infinite redirect loop?

Comment: @KodosJohnson Same thing occurs regardless of the url called. Possibly something to do with headers already been sent. ob_flush doesn't seem to help. Nothing showing up in the error logs.

Comment: Are you expecting the browser to redirect to a new page from an ajax call that receives a header redirect? Or are you expecting the ajax itself to be redirected to another script which returns data for ajax to handle?

Comment: @IncredibleHat Expecting the php script called by ajax to redirect

Comment: The only other thing that sticks out to me is that you are sending a `Status:` header with a http status code but I don't think that is the proper way to send the status code. Since you are doing a location redirect, it automatically sends a redirect status code of 302 so you don't need the `Status:` header. Also, it looks like you are trying to use http status code 100, but as I mentioned, the status code for redirect should be 302. Though your code should work regardless of this.

Comment: But try removing that `header('Status: ' . $status);` line and see if that does anything.